# fixed length string visual basic

Tags: visual-studio, basic

I am using Visual Basic 2010 and I 'd like to make a structure which includes an array with 4 elements each one is a string with 8 chars length
I tried:

```
Structure Vessels
    <VBFixedString(3)> Dim Vsl_Code As String
    <VBFixedString(30)> Dim Vsl_Descr As String
    <VBFixedArray(3)> Dim Vsl_IMO As string * 8
End Structure
```

but it doesn't work. **Vsl_IMO** is a fixed length string of 8 chars. How can I declare it in order to get the length of an item of type Vessels?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try..

```
    Structure Vessels
        <VBFixedString(3)> Dim Vsl_Code As String
        <VBFixedString(30)> Dim Vsl_Descr As String
        <VBFixedArray(3), VBFixedString(8)> Dim Vsl_IMO() As String
    End Structure
```

Combines the fixed array and fixed string attributes.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Thank you very much.